# Flutter stepper title is not working spaceBetween in rows

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Am using stepper in my project. In rows am using spaceBetween concept. It's working for a normal widgets. But for stepper title it's not working. Please check my code and let me know why it is not working. I have given both sample. Like normal(Testing with icon) and stepper title(Testing Title with icon).

```
   import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Verifi());

class Verifi extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return VerificationPaymentStates();
  }
}

class VerificationPaymentStates extends State<Verifi> {
  int _index=0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hello'),
      ),
      body: _builderStep(),
    );
  }
  Widget _builderStep() => Container(
   child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
     Row(
         mainAxisAlignment:
         MainAxisAlignment
             .spaceBetween,
         children: [
           new Container(
               child: new Text(
                   "Testing",
                   style: TextStyle(
                       fontSize: 16,
                       fontWeight:
                       FontWeight
                           .normal))),
           SizedBox(width: 10),
           ClipRRect(
             borderRadius:
             BorderRadius
                 .circular(50),
             child: Material(
               child: InkWell(
                 child: Padding(
                   padding:
                   const EdgeInsets
                       .all(5),
                   child:Icon(
                     Icons.edit,
                     size: 20,
                   ),
                 ),
                 onTap: () {
                   setState(() {

                   });
                 },
               ),
             ),
           )
         ]),
     Stepper(
       steps: [
         Step(
           title:                             GestureDetector(
               onTap: () {
                 setState(() {
                 });
               },
               child:
               Row(
                   mainAxisAlignment:
                   MainAxisAlignment
                       .spaceBetween,
                   children: [
                     new Container(
                         child: new Text(
                             "Testing Title",
                             style: TextStyle(
                                 fontSize: 16,
                                 fontWeight:
                                 FontWeight
                                     .normal))),
                     SizedBox(width: 10),
                     ClipRRect(
                       borderRadius:
                       BorderRadius
                           .circular(50),
                       child: Material(
                         child: InkWell(
                           child: Padding(
                             padding:
                             const EdgeInsets
                                 .all(5),
                             child:Icon(
                               Icons.edit,
                               size: 20,
                             ),
                           ),
                           onTap: () {
                             setState(() {

                             });
                           },
                         ),
                       ),
                     )
                   ])
           ),
           content: Text("This is our first example."),
         ),
         Step(
           title: Text("Second"),
           content: Text("This is our second example."),
         ),
         Step(
           title: Text("Third"),
           content: Text("This is our third example."),
         ),
         Step(
           title: Text("Forth"),
           content: Text("This is our forth example."),
         ),
       ],
       currentStep: _index,
       onStepTapped: (index) {
         setState(() {
           _index = index;
         });
       },
       controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
           {VoidCallback onStepContinue, VoidCallback onStepCancel}) =>
           Container(),
     )

   ],),

  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's actually working but the problem here you are facing is that `Stepper` is giving a `min` width to its title. You can check it in its source code. The only way to fix is that you create your own stepper.

Comment: You create your own stepper means custom stepper?

Comment: Yes. You can use its source .

Comment: But for that I will take time know. I thought there will be some quick fix.

Comment: You can run your code and check in dart dev tool, you'll see how the title is wrapped in a container with a fixed size.

Comment: I don't have that much knowledge in flutter. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need use somethings like GestureDetector and SizedBox and I removed them. And wrap your `Row` with `SizedBox` which its size is screen size minus title padding (84). here is your code;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Verifi(),
    ),
  );
}


class Verifi extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => VerificationPaymentStates();
}

class VerificationPaymentStates extends State<Verifi> {
  int _index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hello'),
      ),
      body: _builderStep(),
    );
  }

  Widget _builderStep() => Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Text(
                    "Testing",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  child: Material(
                    child: InkWell(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.edit,
                          size: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Stepper(
              steps: [
                Step(
                  title: SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 84,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            "Testing Title",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                        ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          child: Material(
                            child: InkWell(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.edit,
                                  size: 20,
                                ),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {});
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  content: Text("This is our first example."),
                ),
                Step(
                  title: Text("Second"),
                  content: Text("This is our second example."),
                ),
                Step(
                  title: Text("Third"),
                  content: Text("This is our third example."),
                ),
                Step(
                  title: Text("Forth"),
                  content: Text("This is our forth example."),
                ),
              ],
              currentStep: _index,
              onStepTapped: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  _index = index;
                });
              },
              controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                      {VoidCallback onStepContinue,
                      VoidCallback onStepCancel}) =>
                  Container(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
}
```

and here is live demo; https://codepen.io/malibayram91/pen/dyYjRqM